# Get chunk of lines in log file concurrently

Tags: scala

I want to get a chunk of lines in a log file to process concurrently, so I open the file, and then use a slice(n,m) method to read lines in specific range, the line of code as below:

```
val lines = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines().slice((pageRequest.size * pageRequest.index).toInt,
                                (pageRequest.size * pageRequest.index + pageRequest.size).toInt )
```

My concern about the performance when working with a large log file, is this approach fine?

Thanks so much

Comment: I think you should go with scanner read specific number of lines the. Send them to process scanner is fast too as for as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this way is likely appropriate to read sequentially, in this case I want to read and transform log lines in parallel.

Comment: Go for kafka then it allow you to read parallel this is the use case for kafka